# Purely geometric derivation of single parameter t-test in linear regression

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, t-test, chi-squared-test

Let's say we have a linear process of the form $y\sim \vec{x}\cdot \vec{w}+N(0,\sigma)$, where $\vec{x},\vec{w}$ lie in $\mathbb{R}^p$.

I have $n$ data points, and will assume all feature vectors (which lie in $\mathbb{R}^n$) are independent. I will write $S$ for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ spanned by the feature vectors (of dimension $p$).

Let $X$ be the $n\times p$ matrix whose columns are these feature vectors and let $\vec{t}:=X\vec{w}\in S$ be the "true" expected outcomes. Let $\vec{y}$ be the vector of observed $y$ values and $\tilde{y}$ the projection of $\vec{y}$ onto $S$. Let $\vec{\beta}$ be the unique vector with $X\vec{\beta}=\tilde{y}$.

The following can be seen purely from geometry (and radial symmetry of the multivariate normal distribution)

1. $\tilde{y}$ is the nearest element of $S$ to $\vec{y}$ so $\vec{\beta}$ minimizes $\|X\vec{\beta}-\vec{y}\|^2$ and therefore $\vec{\beta}$ are the weights returned by linear regression and $\tilde{y}$ are the fitted values.
2. $\vec{y}-\tilde{y}\in S^\perp$, $\tilde{y}-\vec{t}\in S$, and so $\|\vec{y}-\tilde{y}\|^2+\|\tilde{y}-\vec{t}\|^2=\|\vec{y}-\tilde{t}\|^2$.
3. The distribution of $\vec{y}-\vec{t}$ is the multivariate normal distribution with component-wise variance $\sigma^2$ by assumption. So by radial symmetry of the multivariate normal, we may rotate our frame to see that $\frac{\|\vec{y}-\tilde{y}\|^2}{\sigma^2}$ is $\chi_{n-p}^2$, $\frac{\|\tilde{y}-\vec{t}\|^2}{\sigma^2}$ is $\chi_{p}^2$, and the two are independent. In particular, $\frac{\|\vec{y}-\tilde{y}\|^2}{n-p}$ is an unbiased estimator $\sigma^2$ which is independent of $\|\tilde{y}-\vec{t}\|^2$.
4. $\frac{\|\vec{y}-\vec{t}\|^2}{\|\vec{y}-\tilde{y}\|^2/(n-p)}=\frac{\|\vec{y}-\tilde{y}\|^2+\|\tilde{y}-\vec{t}\|^2}{\|\vec{y}-\tilde{y}\|^2/(n-p)}\sim(n-p)(1+\frac{\chi^2_{p}}{\chi^2_{n-p}})$

In other words, given $\vec{w}$ we can determine the likelihood of our ratio between observed error and observed variance being as large as it is without knowing $\sigma^2$.

I'd like to extend this picture to motivate the $t$-distribution formula for $p$-values of specific components of $\vec{w}$. But the non-orthogonality of the feature vectors keeps throwing me off. Is there a nice proof *without* any calculus and minimal linear algebra?

Comment: answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4839132/615091